# How to parse complex function calls in custom language

Tags: parsing, programming-languages

I'm trying to create a custom programming language for fun, and I've gotten a bit carried away with the syntax I want to support with function calls.

```
uses ConsoleIO

r(int)success start (int) nArgument
    printHelloWorlds
    return 0

printHelloWorld 
    print "Hello world\n"

printHelloWorlds
    getNumberFrom 4 into timesToPrint
    timesPrinted = 0
    printHelloWorld
    timesPrinted = timesPrinted + 1
    if timesPrinted < timesToPrint
        goToLine 17

getNumberFrom (int)number into o(int) out
    name = "John"
    out = 3 + name.findFirstOccurenceOf 'o' + number

r(int) (string)str .findFirstOccurenceOf (char)c
    //later
    return 3
```

Hopefully you can get a basic idea of what I'm trying to do.  To be more specific,

- putting r in front of a variable makes it a return value
- variables are 'declared' just by being referenced
- A function name cannot contain two sequential "name tokens", there must be at least one argument in between each name token (and possibly multiple variables will need commas between them, although I'd rather not require that if I can manage the parsing without that restriction)
- putting o in front of a variable makes it an 'output' value.  In this case the function must write to it before reading, and the variable doesn't need to exist before the function is called (on "getNumberFrom 4 into timesToPrint" timesToPrint does not exist prior to being created when getNumberFrom (int) into o(int) is called

I've already programmed the lexer to:

- Interpret function declarations, deal with scope, handle literals, etc
- Read in regular lines of code and make a list of each token, as well as a list of all the functions that contain each token in their name (if any), recognize if a token is the name of a variable
- I'm not dealing with flow control (the if/goto) yet, they're currently treated just like normal functions

However, now I need to actually figure out what function(s) each line is calling, in which order, and with what inputs, as well as what outputs(the o variables), and I've hit a bit of a road block.  I have no experience with this, and I'm not sure where to start.  I know I'm going to need some kind of recursive function.

Basically, can anyone tell me what type of algorithm I'm looking for, or maybe just some buzz words to start googling to learn more?  Should I be using bison or antlr or whatever, or is a language this flexible/strange going to be too complex for that?

Note: I'm not using Bison or Flex or anything, I'm writing all the code myself in C++

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a complex programming language, you should strongly consider using a parser generator like `bison` or ANTLR to do the parsing for you.  The advantage of such tools is that you can just describe what the rules of your language are, along with what to do when such rules are found, and the tool will automatically generate the parsing code for you.

`bison` supports bottom-up parsers in the LR family: LALR(1), LR(1), GLR(1), and the new IELR(1) algorithms.  These capture a large family of languages, but you need to know a bit about the parsing algorithm in order to fix some of the errors you might encounter (namely, shift/reduce and reduce/reduce).

ANTLR uses LL(*) parsers, which capture a slightly smaller set of languages but tends to work beautifully on many programming languages.

There is no one right answer to your question.  I would use whatever tool you feel more comfortable with and has the right language output.

If you insist on rolling your own parser, then you can actually implement the above algorithms by hand, but it's extremely difficult.  The easiest option is to use a top-down recursive descent parser with backtracking, or to jiggle the grammar until it is LL(1) and then use a simple top-down, non-backtracking parser.  That said, I think you are making things much harder than they need to be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for the IELR reference.  Always good when an old dog learns new tricks.

Comment: After doing a lot of googling about Bison, ANTRl, LL(*) Parsers, etc it seems that they all work on contex-free grammars, and I am fairly certain that my language isn't context free, although I'm not quite sure, as I'm still working to decipher all these wikipedia pages....

Comment: @zacaj- Most programming languages aren't context-free, but they can be thought of as a context-free language with some extra constraints representing things like scoping, etc.  The language you've described certainly looks context-free enough to be parsed with these algorithms.